# Handling PL/SQL Errors: Catch an exception and don't throw it

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle12c

I Have a procedure that throws this exception

```
error_stack -> ORA-00030: El identificador de sesión del usuario no existe.
 error_backtrace -> ORA-06512: en "OF_OWNER.GET_INVOICES", línea 46
 call_stack -> ----- PL/SQL Call Stack -----
  object      line  object
  handle    number  name
00000010DB020548        59  procedure OF_OWNER.GET_INVOICES
000000112A537E58         2  anonymous block
```

But I don't want the procedure to raise any exception in this case, I've tried

```
 ...
 WHEN  'ORA-00030' THEN
 WHEN OTHERS
 ...
```

But I got a compilation error

Comment: try this    `exception
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
               IF SQLCODE != -00030THEN 
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'There is an error' );`

Comment: Out of curiosity - why do you want to ignore that error? It makes no sense - if your procedure does not raise error, something else will most certainly break, since session does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either:

```
BEGIN
  do something
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  IF SQLCODE = -30 THEN
    NULL; -- ignore this particular exception
  ELSE
    RAISE; -- but throw the others
  END IF;
END;
```

Or:

```
DECLARE
  ORA00030 EXCEPTION; -- or any other name you like instead of ORA00030
  pragma EXCEPTION_INIT(ORA00030, -30); -- link your exception name to the code
BEGIN
  do something
EXCEPTION WHEN ORA00030 THEN
  NULL; -- ignore this particular exception
END;
```